# What are the non-obvious problems you encounter, moving from Django to Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Question is for programmers who have used Django and Flask for real projects.

What challenges do you face going to the Flask?

Interested in the situation when there may be unexpected difficulties (after using django).

Specific examples are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use Django for "big" projects and Flask for projects requiring less than a ~300 lines file.

The challenges in moving to Flask are in my sense to go look for the extensions for forms, mails, databases... When you need them, and referring to different documentations. But it is naturally the price of flexibility.

One of the key issue I have been facing was deployment with Fabric. I was used to deploy very quickly with django-fab-deploy and it tooks me a little bit of time to set up a comparable generic deployment solution for Flask.